# Clearing textboxes after sending email

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im working on a form that sends an email on the click of a command button, but after the email is made the text boxes the user must fill in do not automatically clear out. I have provided the code I have below. Is there some other kind of clearing command I am missing maybe?

Thanks in advance :)

```
On Error GoTo errhandle
Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Format(Me!CurrentDate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd") & "# and DiscoverTime= '" & Me!DiscoverTime & "' and TailNumber= '" & Me!TailNumber & "' and FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "email", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
exiterr:
Exit Sub
errhandle:
If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
MsgBox ("Email cancelled!")
End If
Resume exiterr


Me.CurrentDate = Null
Me.DiscoverTime = Null
Me.TailNumber = Null
Me.FleetID = Null
```

Comment: Me.CurrentDate = Null will never be reached because you have resume exitErr which leading to exit the routine prematurely. 
also you should use the full naming method like me.txt_currentDate.value = "" unless its a dataField

Comment: @krish, you do not need to use `.Value`, as it is the default in an MS Forms. Using `.Value`, although is not illegal, it is just redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exiting the Sub before clearing. Try the following.

```
    On Error GoTo errhandle
    Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Format(Me!CurrentDate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd") & "# and DiscoverTime= '" & Me!DiscoverTime & "' and TailNumber= '" & Me!TailNumber & "' and FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "email", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"

    Me.CurrentDate = vbNullString
    Me.DiscoverTime = vbNullString
    Me.TailNumber = vbNullString
    Me.FleetID = vbNullString
exiterr:
    Exit Sub
errhandle:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
        MsgBox ("Email cancelled!")
    End If
    Resume exiterr
```

Comment: I have a side question, is there any reason to use `Me.TailNumber = vbNullString` over `Me.TailNumber = ""` ?

Comment: @Newd `vbNullString` is the same as using `""`. It is my way of coding, as it is always better to use constants where available. Using "" has no harmful effect, `vbNullString` just makes it a bit more elegant to understand the intention of the use of a ZLS.

Comment: Personally I prefer `vbNullString` because it saves me the need to look closer at `""` in order to confirm it is not actually something else like `" "` or `"'"`.

Comment: Im having an issue if the user just closes the email instead of sending it. The boxes do not null out am I still doing somthing wrong?

Comment: Because when a user closes an email, the error 2501 is triggered. So if you want the form to clear if the email was canceled, then place the `exiterr` label just above the `Me.CurrentDate = vbNullString`